# Use alias with order by in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, select, alias

i need to create an select with alias, like this:

```
SELECT*, (adresses.v1 + adresses.v2) AS total FROM adresses ORDER BY distance DESC
```

How can i insert this query in this code below?

```
$objects = $this->Property->find('all', array(
    'recursive' => 2,
    'reformat' => true,
    'conditions' => $conditions,
    'order' => $order,
    'joins' => $joins,
));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try:
$objects = $this->Property->find('all', array(
    'recursive' => 2,
    'reformat' => true,
    'conditions' => $conditions,
    'order' => $order,
    'joins' => $joins,
    'fields' => array('*', '(adresses.v1 + adresses.v2) AS total'),
));
```